# I cannot create a trigger in SQL Server with linked server table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a trigger from a linked server but I have the follow problem:

```
CREATE TRIGGER DBO.TRG_CAMBIO_ESTADO
ON LINKSERVER.TABLA.dbo.OPERACIONES
FOR UPDATE
AS
    IF UPDATE(ID_ESTADO)
    BEGIN
        exec SP_REGULARIZADOR
    END
GO
```

Message:

> Servidor: mensaje 117, nivel 15, estado 1, procedimiento TRG_CAMBIO_ESTADO, línea 3
>   The object name 'LINKSERVER.TABLE.dbo.' contains more than the maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 2.

Comment: You can't create a remote trigger like that. You need to connect to linkserver, then create the trigger on dbo.operaciones. Internally to your trigger, then you can call across to the other server `exec otherserver.database.dbo.SP_REGULARIZADOR ...`

Comment: It's a bad idea for a trigger to touch anything outside of the same database that the table is in. I'd suggest revisiting your design and introduce some kind of queuing of triggered actions (e.g. Service Broker or just a plain table in which requests are made). Also, see [CREATE PROCEDURE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx): "Avoid the use of the **sp_** prefix when naming procedures. This prefix is used by SQL Server to designate system procedures."